# Irish accent get changed to wiered charecter while processing the csv file in php (yii1.1 framework)

Tags: php, excel, csv, yii, fgetcsv

I know there are a lot of similar question has already been asked in this community but unfortunately nothing gonna work for me.

I have a CSV sheet which I need to import in our system. Sheet is getting imported without any issue in Linux (creating the sheet with Libre Office) even with Irish character.

But main problem starts in Windows and iOS environment with excel (MS-excel) where character encoding get changed. And few of the Irish characters like

Ž, Ŕ and many others are getting changed to different symbols.

**P.S** : CSV is working fine if we are creating that through Numbers in iOS.

Below is the php method by which I'm reading the CSV sheet.

```
$path = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'absence_data_file'); // Get the instance of selected file
$target = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Class', 'Year', 'From']; // Valid Header

public static function readCSV($path, $target) {
        $updated_header = array();
        $data = array();
        if ($path->type == 'text/csv' || $path->type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel' || $path->type == 'text/plain' || $path->type == 'text/tsv') {
            $fp = fopen($path->tempName, 'r');
            $encoding_type = mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($path->tempName));
            
            if ($fp !== FALSE) {
                $header = fgetcsv($fp);
                foreach ($header as $h) {
                    $updated_header[] = $h;
                }
                $updated_header = array_map( 'trim', array_values($updated_header));
                if (array_diff($target, $updated_header)) {
                    $errormessage = 'Invalid header format.';
                    return $errormessage;
                } else {
                    while ($ar = fgetcsv($fp)) {
                        $data[] = array_combine($updated_header, $ar);
                    }
                    $data['file_encoding'] = $encoding_type;
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $errormessage = "Invalid File type, You can import CSV files only";
            return $errormessage;
        }
    }
```

Sheet which I'm importing (Check the pic):

[image]

Printing the data (First Record)

[image]

Comment: Do not use mb_detect_encoding, it is detecting wrong encoding, if you are certain it is irish then use exact codepage.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking because the excel shows "Western European (Windows)" encoding when we try to open csv file containing Irish accent. But Once we change that encoding to UTF-8 then Irish character get changed in CSV file as well. If I'm certain about the Irish accent then can you please suggest me what should I need to change in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Irish Codepage, but if it is Western European as you mentioned in your comment, I'm guessing your codepage would be ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-14, and your line of code should be:

```php
$encoding_type = mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($path->tempName), 'ISO-8859-1', true);
```

or just simply following since you are sure its encoding is 'ISO-8859-1'

```php
$encoding_type = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Second and 3rd parameters in [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding) tells the function to strictly try and encode using `ISO-8859-1` if you want to try other codepages at the same time, you can provide a list of comma separated code pages to second parameter, e.g. `UTF-8, ISO-8859-1`

Note that you will need to call [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding) to actually get the file in your desired encoding, so following code will strictly try to decode from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

```php
$UTF8_text =  mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

if you insist in using `fgetcsv`, have a look at (mb_internal_encoding)[https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php], it will set default encoding.